# Aligning Two Vertices Along Edge

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges, faces

I am trying to align vertices A and B.

I need vertex to A move to be vertically in line with vertex B, but retain the horizontal slope of face C, how would I go about doing this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use vertex snapping.

1. Enable *Vertex Snapping > Active*
2. Select both vertices of the edge, the last selected will be *active*
3. Move it left and hover your cursor over the target vertex

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that works however I can't actually move the vertices in the correct direction due the orientation of the handles? How can I align the handles so that they face down the edge of the object - see link

https://gyazo.com/b8b8740dde3e77e4ae76b30129de809b

Comment: Hey :). You need to use a different *Transform Orientation* or create a custom one. Please post this as a new question, we're trying to keep it 1 question per post here :).

Comment: If the moving direction is not align with any axis. Constrain the moving axis. like 'only X then only Y' or 'exclude Z', and do it seperately. But the Snap Active method  seems not possible in object mode.